# make *** [install-recursive]: Error 1 fedora

Tags: linux, apache, makefile, fedora

I'm attempting to install Apache using the make install command. I'm running the command as root. This is the error message that I get.

```
libtool: link: cannot find the library `/home/nicole/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/libexpat.la' or unhandled argument `/home/nicole/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/libexpat.la'
Makefile:93: recipe for target 'libaprutil-1.la' failed
make[2]: *** [libaprutil-1.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nicole/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/apr-util'
/home/nicole/httpd-2.4.25/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nicole/httpd-2.4.25/srclib'
/home/nicole/httpd-2.4.25/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I had to install apr and aprutil in order to configure Apache using the command ./configure --enable-mods-shared=all --prefix=/usr/local/apache. That command was successful, and so was "make clean"

help please!

Comment: Make sure you are root or has access to the specific path.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong...
After typing my command ./configure --enable-mods-shared=all --prefix=/usr/local/apache --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre and running it...
I forgot to do the "make clean" command followed by the "make" command before running "make install"